# Java Create 100MB zipped csv file performance issue

Tags: java, supercsv, zipoutputstream

I need to create 100mb zipped file within 5 seconds which contains a CSV file using java. I have created test.zip which contains the CSV file but it is taking too much time (~30 seconds) to generate the zip file. Here is the code that I've written so far:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
/* Create instance of ZipOutputStream to create ZIP file. */
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

/* Create ZIP entry for file.The file which is created put into the
 * zip file.File is not on the disk, csvFileName indicates only the
 * file name to be put into the zip
 */
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("Test.zip");

zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

/* Create OutputStreamWriter for CSV. There is no need for staging
 * the CSV on filesystem . Directly write bytes to the output stream.
 */
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zipOutputStream, "UTF-8"));

CsvListWriter csvListWriter = new CsvListWriter(bufferedWriter, CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);

/* Write the CSV header to the generated CSV file. */
csvListWriter.writeHeader(CSVGeneratorConstant.CSV_HEADERS);

/* Logic to Write the content to CSV */
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 7000000; rowIdx++) {
    final List<String> rowContent = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < 6; colIdx++) {
        String str = "R" + rowIdx + "C" + colIdx + " FieldContent";
        rowContent.add(str);
    }
    csvListWriter.write(rowContent);
}
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
System.out.println("time==" + elapsedTime / 1000f + "Seconds");

System.out.println("Size=====" + baos.size() / (Math.pow(1024, 2)) + "MB");

csvListWriter.close();
bufferedWriter.close();
zipOutputStream.close();
baos.close();
```

I am using the super csv library, but I have also tried to create zip file in memory without super csv lib without success. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you machine can do this? Cna you try the same thing from the command line. BTW `mb` = `milli-bits`, `MB` = `Mega-Bytes`

Comment: Instead of building up a list of strings, why not write directly to the ZipOutputStream?  This will save you quite a bit of time.

Comment: When you CPU profile this, what do you see and taking the most time?

Comment: Side note: Use try-with-resources to close your streams.

Comment: Instead of building up a `ByteArrayOutputStream,` why not write directly to the target file? You're just wasting time and space.

Comment: @PeterLawrey-
1)100 MB(Mega Bytes),
2)I have also tried to write directly to the ZipOutputStream but its takes more time because of writing every str bytes.like ZipOutputStream.write(str.getBytes());
3)Ofcourse time taken to write csvListWriter.write(rowContent)

Comment: @EJP-I need this zip file in memory because if i am going to write in destination file then it will take more time.

Answer (score 3):

Your test data is about 1GB, which compresses down to 100MB. Depending on your hardware, it may not be possible to achieve < 5s performance.

I've put together a quick and dirty benchmark which highlights the performance impacts of writing to a zip file.

- Write to CSV with `String.join()`: 9.6s
- Write to CSV with Super CSV: 12.7s
- Write to CSV within zip with `String.join()`: 18.6s
- Write to CSV within zip with Super CSV: 22.5s

It appears that there's a little bit of an overhead with using Super CSV (~122%), but just writing to a zip file almost doubles (~190%) the amount of time, regardless of whether Super CSV is used.

Here's the code for the 4 scenarios.

Unlike your provided code, I'm writing directly to a file (I didn't notice any difference between writing to disk vs writing to memory, i.e. `ByteArrayOutputStream`). I've also skipped the `BufferedWriter` on the Super CSV examples, because it already uses that internally, and I've used try-with-resources to make things cleaner.

```
@Test
public void testWriteToCsvFileWithSuperCSV() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try (FileOutputStream csvFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("supercsv.csv"));
         ICsvListWriter writer = new CsvListWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(csvFile, "UTF-8"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE)
    ){
        for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 7000000; rowIdx++) {
            final List<String> rowContent = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < 6; colIdx++) {
                String str = "R" + rowIdx + "C" + colIdx + " FieldContent";
                rowContent.add(str);
            }
            writer.write(rowContent);
        }
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Writing to CSV with Super CSV took " + (elapsedTime / 1000f) + " seconds");
}

@Test
public void testWriteToCsvFileWithinZipWithSuperCSV() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try (FileOutputStream zipFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("supercsv.zip"));
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(zipFile);
         ICsvListWriter writer = new CsvListWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos, "UTF-8"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE)
    ){

        ZipEntry csvFile = new ZipEntry("supercsvwithinzip.csv");
        zos.putNextEntry(csvFile);

        for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 7000000; rowIdx++) {
            final List<String> rowContent = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < 6; colIdx++) {
                String str = "R" + rowIdx + "C" + colIdx + " FieldContent";
                rowContent.add(str);
            }
            writer.write(rowContent);
        }
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Writing to CSV within zip file with Super CSV took " + (elapsedTime / 1000f) + " seconds");
}

@Test
public void testWriteToCsvFileWithStringJoin() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try (FileOutputStream textFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("join.csv"));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(textFile, "UTF-8"));
    ){

        for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 7000000; rowIdx++) {
            final List<String> rowContent = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < 6; colIdx++) {
                String str = "R" + rowIdx + "C" + colIdx + " FieldContent";
                rowContent.add(str);
            }
            writer.append(String.join(",", rowContent) + "\n");
        }
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Writing to CSV with String.join() took " + (elapsedTime / 1000f) + " seconds");
}

@Test
public void testWriteToCsvFileWithinZipWithStringJoin() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try (FileOutputStream zipFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("join.zip"));
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(zipFile);
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos, "UTF-8"));
    ){

        ZipEntry csvFile = new ZipEntry("joinwithinzip.csv");
        zos.putNextEntry(csvFile);

        for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 7000000; rowIdx++) {
            final List<String> rowContent = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < 6; colIdx++) {
                String str = "R" + rowIdx + "C" + colIdx + " FieldContent";
                rowContent.add(str);
            }
            writer.append(String.join(",", rowContent) + "\n");
        }
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Writing to CSV within zip with String.join() took " + (elapsedTime / 1000f) + " seconds");
}
```